# Capistrano and rvm the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

I have this situation on my client workstation.

When i try to make a deploy, with

```
cap deploy
```

i get this error message:

```
capistrano is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

Ok! But i don't want to add it to gemfile. I want to use it system wide. The gem is currently installed.

Some information about the binary:

```
~/Code/ecommerce (master ✔) ᐅ which cap
cap: aliased to bundled_cap


~/Code/ecommerce (master ✔) ᐅ which bundled_cap
  bundled_cap () {
    _run-with-bundler cap $@
  }
```

Any idea? I'm in wrong?

Comment: Ok i'm thinking is an issue regarding oh-my-szh and the bundler plugin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `bundle exec` is being prepended to your `cap deploy` command.

Are you using something like [bundler-exec](https://github.com/gma/bundler-exec) or [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/)?

Comment: I used `noglob cap deploy`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the main problem was the oh-my-zsh aliases and the bundler plugin

this is the file
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/bundler/bundler.plugin.zsh

now is working fine again!

Comment: Thank You for mentioning that!